# File changes after a mmap in OS X / iOS

Tags: linux, macos, memory, mmap, darwin

What happens if, after I memory-map a file using `mmap` and flag `MAP_PRIVATE`, I make changes to the underlying file while in the same process? Will the `mmap` memory pick up the changes?

In Linux, the man page says:

> MAP_PRIVATE: Create a private copy-on-write mapping. Updates to the mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file, and are not carried through to the underlying file. It is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.

So in Linux, the answer is "unspecified".

In Mac OS X however it only says:

> MAP_PRIVATE: Modifications are private (copy-on-write).

I did a quick sample tool that appears to show that making changes doesn't affect private mappings. But there's no other proof of this.

Comment: Well I think you have proved the implementation using your sample app, but you can look at the XNU kernel source (see http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/) to see how it's implemented (you need to find `__mmap()`).

Comment: @trojanfoe, I did some snooping around but couldn't find `__mmap`. My sample app only shows *in one particular case* that the change doesn't affect private mappings, I can't prove it *in all cases* without documentation or code. Has anyone else tried this?